# Python: Using arguments as variables

Tags: python

I want to use arguments which will then be translated into variable that will hold a value:

I get some values from a CSV file then upload it to Googles' Sheet Docs.

Here is a snippet of my code [`mycode.py`]:

```
f101 = open('/home/some_directory/101_Hrs.csv')
f102 = open('/home/some_directory/102_Hrs.csv')
f103 = open('/home/some_directory/103_Hrs.csv')
f112 = open('/home/some_directory/112_Hrs.csv')

csv_f101 = csv.reader(f101)
csv_f102 = csv.reader(f102)
csv_f103 = csv.reader(f103)
csv_f112 = csv.reader(f112)
```

I want to use an argument (101,102,103 or 112) from the terminal (for example `mycode.py 101`), where I can use the [`101`] to be concatenated with the `f` to get`f101` and also `open('/home/some_directory/[101]_Hrs.csv')` where [`101`] is a number that can be replaced by the argument from the terminal.

How is this done?

Comment: Instead of dynamically creating variables, you want to use a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Also you may want to look into [for loops](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) ;).

Comment: You don't need separate variables.  Use a for loop to open a file and upload it, then do the next file, etc.  To substitute something in the file name you use string formatting: print  'abc-{0}'.format(101)  https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: maybe `os.walk()`  with a `loop`  make you happy.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of easy tutorials for using input arguments in python programs:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-command-line-arguments-argv-example/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

The basic idea is to use the inbuilt `sys` module, which lets you access the inputs via `argv`.

```
import sys

nInputs = len(sys.argv)

print 'Number of arguments = ', nInputs
print 'Inputs = ', str(sys.argv)

if (nInputs >= 2):
    strFilename = '/home/some_directory/' + sys.argv[1] + '_Hrs.csv'
    print 'Filename = ', strFilename
```

Then when you run:

```
>> python mycode.py 101
Number of arguments = 2
Inputs = ['mycode.py', '101']
Filename = /home/some_directory/101_Hrs.csv
```

Comment: Should there be a `:` after the `if (nInputs >= 2)` ?

Comment: Also -  `strInputs[1]`  indexes 1st character from `['mycode.py', '101']` which is `[` and `strInputs[4]` = `m` ...`

Answer (score 0):

Check out `argparse`, which has more features than `sys.argv`. You don't necessarily need all of them with your current requirements, but it is more flexible and lets you avoid some reinvention:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('arguments', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
print('number of supplied arguments:{}'.format(len(args.arguments)))
for argument in args.arguments:
    print('supplied argument:{}'.format(argument))
```

It also has an excellent tutorial written by a frequent Stack Overflow contributor: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html